# Error: There is no source with this ID in mapbox-gl-js

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I want to remove  source and layer from the map. Whenever i want to remove sources and layerrs form map then i am using `removeSourceAndLayers()` function.

```js
const removeSourceAndLayers=(map)=>{
        for(var i=0;i<dataSet.length;i++){
            try{
                // source or layer might not pesent
                // which we are trying to remove
                if(map.getLayer(`empty-source-${i}`))
                    map.removeLayer(`empty-source-${i}`);
                if(map.getLayer(`complete-source-${i}`))
                    map.removeLayer(`complete-source-${i}`);
                if(map.getSource(`empty-source-${i}`))
                    map.removeSource(`empty-source-${i}`);
                if(map.getSource(`complete-source-${i}`));
                    map.removeSource(`complete-source-${i}`);
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error.

```js
DynamicRoute.jsx:39 Error: There is no source with this ID
    at i.removeSource (mapbox-gl.js:35)
    at r.removeSource (mapbox-gl.js:35)
    at removeSourceAndLayers (DynamicRoute.jsx:37)
    at clean (DynamicRoute.jsx:93)
    at commitHookEffectListUnmount (react-dom.development.js:19710)
    at commitPassiveHookEffects (react-dom.development.js:19768)
```

I am checking if source and layer present with the current id then remove otherwise continue.But, still error is appearing.

***jsx:39*** line is `console.log(e);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last if statement has a ; at the end, if you remove it, it will work.

```
if(map.getSource(`complete-source-${i}`)); // <---
    map.removeSource(`complete-source-${i}`);
```

The way your code is written now, it will have the same result as the code below, map.removeSource() is always called:

```
if(map.getSource(`complete-source-${i}`)) {
}

map.removeSource(`complete-source-${i}`);
```